# Permanently exclude vssver2.scc file from the filesets in Ant script

Tags: ant, visual-sourcesafe

Ant by default excludes `vssver.scc` file from all filesets. This is very convenient.

But VSS2005 uses `vssver2.scc` file for the same purpose :(

Can I modify Ant's default excludes somehow? 
I do not like an idea to add

```
<exclude name="vssver*.scc"/>
```

to each fileset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there in the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html):

> defaultexcludes   indicates whether [default excludes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes) should be used or
>   not (yes | no); default excludes are used when omitted.

which links to

> This is the default list; note that you can modify the list of default
>   excludes by using the [defaultexcludes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/defaultexcludes.html) task.

which links to

> Alters the default excludes for all subsequent processing in the
>   build, and prints out the current default excludes if desired.